# Code refactoring, how to disintegrate two two static functions without making parent functions non static

Tags: java, algorithm, spring-mvc, generics, dependency-injection

Context :

> We are refectoring the code in order to move to micro services. We've
>   multiple products(A, B, C and some common code for A,B,C in monolithic
>   service). now we creating new sandbox for common code.

Problem :

```
User.java
    Class User {
     public **static** void init(){
       List<Items> users=Items.getItemsList();
     }


       }


Items.java           
        Class Items {
             public **static** Items getItemsList(){
              //many static functions and dependancy 

               return items;
             }
            }
```

> So here, both the functions are static and i want to move only User.java
>   to new sandbox not Items.java. how can i disintegrate this dependancy.
>   and i can not make User.init() non-static

Comment: "i _[sic]_ can not make `User.init()` non-static"
What a shame since that's exactly what you should do.

Comment: What does “creating new sandbox” or “to move [only] User.java to new sandbox” mean, how does this “disintegrate this dependancy [sic]”, and why does it imply that the method’s `static` modifier has to change?

Comment: @Holger
Because there are multiple products which are using User.java. so we are creating a new sandbox for common files like User.java, Order.java etc...
so the scenario will be 
Products A's Sandbox +  common files' Sandbox
Products B's Sandbox +  common files' Sandbox.....which ultimately lead to microservice. do you have any other idea on this ? Pls suggest ?

Comment: @LewBloch  It's legacy code. unfortunately i can not make it non static because User.init() starts at the time of server deploy.

Comment: You still didn’t explain what you mean with “sandbox”. It’s also unclear why this should “ultimately lead to microservice”, but anyway, *why does it imply that the method’s static modifier has to change?* Since your question is about that `static` modifier, that’s the most important question.

Comment: @Holger new sandbox means shifting into new java project. and User.java will be new java project and no dependancy will there related to Items.java because only product is using Items.java. However, User.java will be used by multiple products. 
* note : We are moving all common files in to new java project so we can compile it without have any dependancy on any other company's product. similarly. Any product's source code should be also compile with common java project aka new sandbox's jar.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming *sandbox* means an independent project that produces a jar, then 'Items` must also exist in the sandbox, otherwise it won't compile.

But you could extract an interface from `Items` to something such as `IItems` (forgive the terrible name).

```
public interface IItems {
    // methods...
}
```

which is included in the sandbox.

And create an interface for a factory such as:

```
public interface IItemsFactory {
    List<IItem> create();
}
```

which is also included in the sandbox.

The ugly part is keeping `User.init()` as static.  Using a hacky IoC pattern, set an implementation of an `IItemsFactory` into User.  The factory will also have to be static.  So `User` becomes something like:

```
public class User {
    private static volatile IItemsFactory factory;

    public static setFactory(IItemsFactory factory) {
        User.factory = factory;
    }

   public static void init() {
       List<IItems> users = factory.getItemsList();
   }
}
```

The A, B, and C projects are responsible for providing an implementation of IItemFactory and setting it before calling `User.init()`.

This is half baked and those static methods need to go away during the next refactoring iteration.  Still use the IoC pattern, but inject the factory as part of the `User` constructor.

```
public class User {
    private IItemsFactory factory;

    public User(IItemsFactory factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

   public void init() {
       List<IItems> users = factory.getItemsList();
   }
}
```

Comment: When the following code will be called   ?  /setting factory/ initializing  

 public User(IItemsFactory factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

Comment: I'm assuming `init()` is called somewhere in products/projects A, B, C.  There would need to be a minor change there to set the factory before calling `init()`.